# optimizing div + screen resize JS block

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, resize, screen

I'm struggling to figure out what the best way would be to optimize this code. I'm currently only using width @media tags, and JS seems to be the only reliable way I can control a series of very specific variables to adjust this div element.

It's currently a mess I realize, but I wanted to get feedback to see if there are any glaring issues. Still learning, so go easy on me.

Thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var elementHeight = $('.hs-caption').height();
    var screenHeight = jQuery(window).height();
    var upcomingHeader = $('.fold-header').height() * 2.0;
    if (screenHeight > 960) {
    var heightOffset = 220;         
    } else {
    var heightOffset = 200; 
    } 
    var totalHeight = elementHeight + heightOffset;

function fullscreen(){
    jQuery('#hero').css({
        width: jQuery(window).width(),
        height: jQuery(window).height()
    });
}  
function setToCenterOfParent(element, parent, ignoreWidth, ignoreHeight){
    parentWidth = $(parent).width();
    parentHeight = $(parent).height();  
    elementWidth = $(element).width();
    elementHeight = $(element).height();
    if(!ignoreWidth)
        $(element).css('left', parentWidth/2 - elementWidth/2);
    if(!ignoreHeight)
        $(element).css('top', heightOffset);
}   

function scalar(){
  if (window.innerHeight < (totalHeight * 1.25) + upcomingHeader) {
        console.log("screenHeight is less than elementHeight");       
        $('.hs-info p').css({
            display: 'none'
        }),
        $('.hs-info .btn-slide').css({
            padding: '10px 0px 0px 0px'
        }),
        $('.hs-sponsor').css({
            display: 'none'
        })
    } else {
        console.log("screenHeight is NOT less than elementHeight");       
        $('.hs-info .btn-slide').css({
            padding: '0px'
        }),
        $('.hs-sponsor').css({
            display: 'block'
        }),
        $(".hs-info p").css({
            display: 'block'
        })
    }
}

setToCenterOfParent( $('.hs-caption'), document.body, true, false);
fullscreen();
scalar();

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    scalar();
    setToCenterOfParent( $('.hs-caption'), document.body, true, false);
    fullscreen();         
});

console.log("height:", elementHeight);
console.log("total height:", elementHeight + heightOffset); 
console.log("screenHeight:", screenHeight); 
console.log("heightOffset:", heightOffset); 
console.log("upcomingHeader:", upcomingHeader);     
});
```

Comment: Your last line is not in the code block.

Comment: Will this code be use on element other than `hs-caption` ?

Comment: no it wont -- it's basically a homepage element that adjusts according to the viewer's device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the target is not very clear, I can only do some small code editing to make it more easy to read, and maybe a little performance improvement.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Define share variables.
  var element = $('.hs-caption');
  var elementWidth, elementHeight;
  var screenWidth, screenHeigth;
  var upcomingHeader = $('.fold-header').height() * 2.0;
  var heightOffset;
  var totalHeight;
  var HEIGHT_RATIO = 1.25;
  var paddingElements = $('.hs-info .btn-slide');
  var displayElements = $('.hs-info p, .hs-sponsor');
  var RESIZE_DELEY = 200;
  var delayedHandler = null;

  function onResize() {
    updateSetting();
    setToCenterOfParent(element, $(document.body), true, false);
    fullscreen();
    scalar();
  };

  function scalar() {
    var innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var totalElementHeight = totalHeight * HEIGHT_RATIO + upcomingHeader;
    var isScreenSmaller = (innerHeight < totalElementHeight);
    var padding = isScreenSmaller ? '10px 0px 0px 0px' : '0px';
    var display = isScreenSmaller ? 'none' : 'block';
    paddingElements.css('padding', padding);
    displayElements.css('display', display);
  }

  function updateSetting(){
    screenWidth = $(window).width();
    screenWidth = $(window).height();
    elementWidth = element.width();
    elementHeight = element.height();
    heightOffset = (screenHeight > 960) ? 220 : 200;
    totalHeight = elementHeight + heightOffset;
  }

  function fullscreen() {
    $('#hero').css({
      width: screenWidth,
      height: screenHeigth
    });
  }

  function setToCenterOfParent(element, parent, ignoreWidth, ignoreHeight) {
    var parentWidth = parent.width();
    var parentHeight = parent.width();
    if (!ignoreWidth) {
      element.css('left', parentWidth/2 - elementWidth/2);
    }
    if (!ignoreHeight) {
      element.css('top', heightOffset);
    }
  }

  // Init
  onResize();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    // Don't do this too often
    if (delayedHandler !== null) {
      clearTimeout(delayedHandler);
    }
    // Delayed the function to be executed, so it only updates when user stop
    // resizing for a fixed amount of time.
    delayedHandler = setTimeout(onResize, RESIZE_DELEY);
  });

  console.log("height:", elementHeight);
  console.log("total height:", elementHeight + heightOffset);
  console.log("screenHeight:", screenHeight);
  console.log("heightOffset:", heightOffset);
  console.log("upcomingHeader:", upcomingHeader);
});
```

The idea is:

1. Pull out all of the elements that will be queried again and again, like `$('.hs-info .btn-slide')` and `$('.hs-info p, .hs-sponsor')`, also `$('.hs-caption')` seems to be widely used, pull it out.
2. Do samething to variables, here I'm not sure if you would use `setToCenterOfParent` to other elements, but I'll try to input the jquery wrapped element, so I can directly use jquery on them in the function.
3. `elementWidth/elementHeight` here is not clear whether it'll change or not, so I remain the code not edited.
4. Add a `settimeout` to resize, so jquery won't do lots of computation during the user resizing his window, and 0.2 sec's delay should be fast enough so user won't feel a delay(or you can adjust RESIZE_DELEY to a even smaller number).
5. unless you're using some library that will conflict with jquery, keep code style same is preferable, so I change all `jQuery(foo).bar` to `$(foo).bar` for consistency.

I believe this should be the most we can do, if there's no example like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), to demonstrate what this code is for.

Comment: i wish I had the reputation to upvote this (will come back to it when i can and +1) -- this helps a lot, and gives me enough to research / push the concept further -- i really appreciate you taking the time to do this!